# Streaming webservice call in flex

Tags: apache-flex, soap, actionscript, upload, urlloader

I am trying to create a file upload in a flex/air application that sends information to a .NET wcf SOAP webservice. The file upload also has to have progress indicating events. The service uses a Stream as a MessageBodyMember to allow streaming upload. My input looks a little like this:

```
[MessageContract]
public class SendFileRequestMessage : IDisposable
{
    public string UserName;

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public Stream FileData;
}
```

and the service looks like this:

```
public interface IFileTransferService
{
    [OperationContract]
    SendFileResponseMessage SendFile(SendFileRequestMessage request);
}
```

Now when i create a proxy class in VS2010 i get a Stream object for FileData. If I do the same in Flash Builder 4.7 the FileData is interpreted as a ByteArray. I already looked into FileUpload and UrlLoader in my client but i can't get the body member set. My action script now looks like this 
*not working*

```
var dataToSave:XML = <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:q0="http://mystuff/uploadservice/v1"><soapenv:Body><q0:SendFile/></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>

            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost:31454/Uploadhandler.svc");
            request.requestHeaders = new Array(new URLRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://mystuff/uploadservice/v1/IFileTransferService/SendFile"));
            request.data = dataToSave;
            request.contentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";

            request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            loader.load(request);
```

So how can do a streaming file upload to a soap service from flex? Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: My guess is that dataToSave must be base64 encoded.

Comment: but dataToSave is my soap message now. How would I get it to stream data? Like a fileUpload control in action script...

Comment: Oops... sorry. Didn't read carefully. Posted an answer as its too big for comment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with .NET SOAP model, but if it expects standard http content dispositions for file data you can try getting FileReference object for your file and then pass your URLRequiest in its upload method. In your case this could  be like

```
        ... Create class level variable ...
        var fr:FileReference = new FileReference();

        ... Obtain file reference somewhere ...
        //Set handlers for Filereference events 
        fr.browse(); //Obtain actual file reference  


        ... Somewhere in selectHandler chain....

        var dataToSave:XML = <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:q0="http://mystuff/uploadservice/v1"><soapenv:Body><q0:SendFile/></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>

        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost:31454/Uploadhandler.svc");
        request.requestHeaders = new Array(new URLRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://mystuff/uploadservice/v1/IFileTransferService/SendFile"));
        request.data = dataToSave;
        request.contentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

        //Do POST
        fr.upload(request);
```

This [Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#includeExamplesSummary) contains examples for using FileReference.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your help. I am now receiving an error from the service stating: 'HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----------GI3Ij5Ij5ei4ae0Ij5ei4KM7ae0ei4' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.' I'll try to fix it and will post any progres..

Comment: Still truggling with it. It seems that my service is only able to accept text/xml...

Comment: Well, something deep in my memory hints, that content type of FileRefenence cannot be changed too. Have to construct HTTP request manually, I believe.

Comment: Do you mean urlloader? I think the progress event than no longer works as shown here http://forums.adobe.com/message/2902327 unless you do separate requests...

Comment: Yes I thought of Urlloader. Progress events could be problem. But do you really need progress bar? Can some busy cursor used together with timeout timer satisfy your needs?

Comment: I already had that kind of functionality and in the end we stook with that. IMHO having a progress bar was a LOT of extra effort